# React State is rolling back to previous value

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem which I could not figure out. I have this function which calculates the total price:

```js
const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);

const calcTotalPrice = (itemss) => {
  var sum = null;

  itemss.forEach(function (item) {
    sum += item?.Quantity * item?.Prijs;
  });

  setTotalPrice(sum);
  console.log(totalPrice);
};
```

It works great, but when I update the quantity of a product the state does not update. Well, it does but then rolls back to it's previous value. Here is the output I am getting:

```
570
443
467
```

Which is very weird. The top value is the new value, the second is the old and I don't know where the third one is coming from. The function is called everytime the function getItems() is called:

```js
async function getItems() {
  setLoading(true);
  db.collection(`rooms/${roomId}/Items`).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    const itemss = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      itemss.push(doc.data());
    });
    setItems(itemss);
    calcTotalPrice(itemss);
    setLoading(false);
  });
}

useEffect(() => {
  getItems();
}, []);
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What if you log your `totalPrice` correctly in a separate `useEffect` with `totalPrice` as a dependency, so it is logged ***after*** `setTotalPrice(sum)` is processed? The `useEffect` calling `getItems` has an empty dependency array, so I wouldn't expect to see more than a single console log anyway. How are you getting three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTotalPrice(sum);` won't reflect `totalPrice` immediately because setting state function is asynchronous. That's why `console.log` doesn't seem to be working properly.

Also, `onSnapshot` listener will be called every time collection data is changed (added/modified/removed). Here's an example for your information.

```js
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
        });
    });
```